# Join (MATCH) with multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, join, match, spreadsheet

In Excel, we would like to join column D and E with A. In order to do so, we already tried the following approach involving INDEX and MATCH function:

Column B is the result of the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2;D:D;0));"";INDEX(D:D;MATCH(A2;D:D;0)))
```

The table looks like this:

[image: What we have]

and we would like this as our final result:

[image: What we want]

So, what we basically want is to match every instance of D that has the same value as A and assign the corresponding value of E to that row and store the result in a seperate column. However, at this point we are only able to perform this operation with column D, leaving out some of the non-matching records.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand what you want. Please post a screen shot of your desired results, given your data table.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the reply. I have now corrected the post as requested.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C2:  =IF(A2=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$8,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

Comment: We are most thankful for your solution which is exactly what we requested. Moreover, we thank you for taking your time to manually enter the values as we were unable to find a way to post the table directly. Your method is helping us perform similar tasks in the future.

Comment: @KristofferJeberg To post textual data directly, try using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).  After you paste the results into your Q or A, format the table as "code" and you will have data that can be copied for troubleshooting.

Comment: Excellent. I have saved the markdown generator for future reference. And marked your answer as the solution. Thanks again.